# this question is related to discriminant analysis

Tags: discriminant-analysis

[image: **i want to proof 11-13 using the equation 11-12 help me?can anyone help me?**]

this is related to quadratic discriminant analysis. I want to prove the 11-13 using the result  11.2 as shown in the image.Can anyone suggest the steps to complete the proof?

Comment: The question asks you carry out "exercise 11.5."  Why not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $B(x,y):=\frac12x'\Sigma^{-1}y$ is a symmetric bilinear form, therefore:
$$-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_1)'\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_1)+\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_2)'\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_2)$$
$$=-B(x-\mu_1,x-\mu_1)+B(x-\mu_2,x-\mu_2)$$
$$=-B(x,x)+B(x,\mu_1)+B(\mu_1,x)-B(\mu_1, \mu_1)+B(x,x)-B(x,\mu_2)-B(\mu_2,x)+B(\mu_2, \mu_2)$$
$$=2B(\mu_1,x)-2B(\mu_2,x)-B(\mu_1,\mu_1)+B(\mu_2,\mu_2)$$
$$=2B(\mu_1-\mu_2,x)+B(\mu_2-\mu_1,\mu_2+\mu_1)$$
$$=2B(\mu_1-\mu_2,x)-B(\mu_1-\mu_2,\mu_1+\mu_2)$$
$$=(\mu_1-\mu_2)'\Sigma^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1-\mu_2)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1+\mu_2)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it